# How the 'as' keyword works in exception handling?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code below

```py
>>> try:
...     a = 12 / 0
... except Exception as e:
...     print(e)
... 
division by zero
>>>
```

Google says 'the `as` keyword is used to create an alias.'

Then why this below code does not work?

```py
>>> try:
...     a = 12 / 0
... except Exception:
...     print(Exception)
... 
<class 'Exception'>
>>>
```

According to some sources it creates an object of the `Exception` class.

Then why the following code print nothing?

```py
>>> try:
...     a = 12 / 0
... except Exception:
...     a = Exception()
...     print(a)
... 

>>>
```

My questions are:

1. If the `as` keyword acts as an alias, why the second example did not work (instead of printing error it printed reference to `Exception` class)?
2. If the `as` keyword creates an object of the `Exception` class, why the third example did not work (instead of printing the error it did not print anything)?

Comment: `as e` binds the raised exception to `e`.  `Exception` is an exception class.  So while `e` may be an instance of `Exception`, they are hardly the same thing.  `Exception()` simply creates an instance of the `Exception` class, and has nothing to do with the previously raised exception.

Comment: Google is not the arbiter of Python - the quote seems to be from wwwschools, rather than an authority like [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misreading the reference.  The `as`  keyword is used to create an alias, but only in the `import` statement.  Its meaning with `except` is entirely different.  In that case, it merely declares a variable that will hold the exception object.  If you say `except Exception as e`, then `e` will be an object of type `Exception`.

In your final example:

```
try:
    a = 12/0
except Exception:
    a = Exception()
    print(a)
```

You are not capturing the exception that was thrown.  Instead, you are creating a brand new Exception option.  Such an object does not yet hold an exception, so nothing prints.  If you want the exception that was caught, you must use the `as` clause.

Comment: I would just add that `e` is an instance of type `Exception` or a subclass of `Exception`

Comment: Why _"or a subclass"_? Isn't `e` an instance and only an instance of the `Exception` class?

Comment: @accdias `except Exception as e:` catches any exception that is an instance of `Exception` or any subclass of `Exception`, pretty much every built-in exception is a subclass of `Exception` so this will catch all exceptions and `e` will be an instance of whatever exception was raised

Comment: Oh! Now I got it. I completely forgot that `Exception` has subclasses.